# Cant change button colors and list-dividers jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

http://getwiddly.com/dm/index.html

I am having issues changing the color of the buttons when clicked.  It seems its inheriting the default theme when you let go of the buttons click, as it turns blue. I would like it the "g" theme color or the color set of my own, not blue.

http://getwiddly.com/dm/index.html#lunchmenu

I want to set the list-divider color but I can customize the color. I want it green but when I apply the "g" theme for data-dividertheme it uses some other light color part of the theme instead the green part....So I applied it to the

and it works....only after you highlight/hover the title, for example "SMALL PLATES...." if you highlight/hover this, it changes to the right color.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest rolling your own theme as editing the current jQM CSS can be cumbersome and you might overlook something:

- http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/